# conditional using declaration

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, generic-programming

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<bool enable, typename T>
struct foo;

template<typename T>
struct foo<false , T>
{
    //nothing
};

template<typename T>
struct foo<true , T>
{
    void say_hello() 
    { 
        cout << "Hello !" << endl;
    }

    protected:

        int m_some_data_when_I_enabled{};
};

template<bool Enable, typename T>
struct bar
    :
    foo<Enable , T>
{
    //And there are lots of functions and members

    //Here I need conditional 'using'
    using foo<Enable , T>::say_hello;

    void say_hello(int different_signature)
    {

    }
};

struct duck {   };

int main(int, char**) {
    bar<true , duck> enabled_bar;
    bar<false , duck> disabled_bar;
}
```

It gives an error when I declare bar. It makes sense to me. So I need something like :

```
template<typename = typename std::enable_if<Enable>::type>
using foo<Enable , T>::say_hello();
```

I know I can solve the problem with specializing 'bar' but It has some members and in that case I would duplicate lots of codes. Is there a different, maybe tricky,  way ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare a deleted `say_hello` in your 1st foo which makes the `using` statement in `bar` legal.

```
template<typename T>
struct foo<false , T>
{
    void say_hello() = delete;
};
```

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/c1pu3P) is the full example.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a simple forwarding overload, and use SFINAE to conditionally disable it when the member does not exist in the base class. Like this:

```
template<typename V = T, typename = decltype(&foo<Enable, V>::say_hello)>
void say_hello() 
{ 
    bar::foo::say_hello();
}
```

<kbd>[See it Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/041639a1fd03b6ab)</kbd>

We need to use `&foo<Enable, V>::say_hello` instead of `&foo<Enable, T>::say_hello` to delay the check and make it happen during substitution (when an attempt is made to call the function) as opposed to it happening when `bar` is instantiated.

If the member doesn't exist, overload resolution will discard the new overload (on account of an ill-formed substitution), as though it never existed.

But it's worth noting that this won't work for overload sets (because one cannot take a pointer-to-member of an overload set). It will only work if you know there is only a single overload, which can have its pointer-to-member formed unambiguously.