# Default for resolving ambiguous access

Tags: c++, templates, multiple-inheritance

Consider the following classes:

```cpp
class VisitableNode {
public:
    virtual void Visit();
};

class VisitableGraph {
public:
    virtual void Visit();
};

class OtherNode {
};

class OtherGraph {
};

template<class G, class N>
class GraphNode : public G, public N {
};

class MyVisitableGraph : public GraphNode<VisitableGraph, VisitableNode> {
};

class MyOtherGraph : public GraphNode<OtherGraph, OtherNode> {
};

MyVisitableGraph visitableGraph;
visitableGraph.Visit(); // Ambiguous access. Could be either VisitableGraph::Visit or VisitableNode::Visit.

MyOtherGraph otherGraph;
```

The ambiguous access issue can be solved with `using` inside `MyVisitableGraph`:

```cpp
class MyVisitableGraph : public GraphNode<VisitableGraph, VisitableNode> {
    using VisitableGraph::Visit;
};
```

But, is there a way to resolve the ambiguity inside `GraphNode` instead? I can't just do `using G:Visit`, as then `MyOtherGraph` would not compile. Is it for example possible to specify that by default, `G` should have higher precedence than `N` in order to resolve ambiguities in `GraphNode`?

Comment: you are missing some `;` and the method is private.

Comment: Indeed! Thanks :)

Comment: i dont fully understand the question. `visitableGraph.Visit();` should always call `VisitableGraph::Visit()` ? when should `VisitableNode::Visit()` be called?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number `visitableGraph` is of type `MyVisitableGraph`, which inherits from `GraphNode`, which inherits from `VisitableGraph` and `VisitableNode`. Both `VisitableGraph` and `VisitableNode` have a `Visit` member function. Hence the ambiguity.

Comment: yes there is ambiguity, but you say you dont want the using because then only one method can be called. When do you want to call the other? Anyhow, see answer, I hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56206112/conditional-using-declaration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by @463035818_is_not_a_number, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56206231/2459228) gave a solution:

```cpp
template<class G, class N>
class GraphNode : public G, public N {
public:
    template<class = decltype(&G::Visit)>
    void Visit() {
        G::Visit();
    }
};
```

It loses the `virtual` specifier, so it might not always be usable. And it is very hacky, so I don't think I'll use it. A way to say that all ambiguities should be resolved by using `G` over `N` would have been nicer.

Comment: fwiw, SFINAE looks very hacky at first, but often it is the only viable way. Once you got used to it, it does not look that hacky anymore. Add a comment to the code in case you think it isnt obvious what it does